# Crystal report failed to open the connection in crystal report viewer in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have created a winform which will display a crystal report in crystal report viewer. I keep getting the below error after the progress spinner stops.
[image: Error]

This is my code:

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
cryRpt.Load(filePath);
rptViewerFinan.ReportSource = cryRpt;
rptViewerFinan.Refresh();
```

When I open the .rpt file directly in crystal report it works fine.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you checked the credentials of database like username and password .

Comment: there is no username and password

Comment: Did you get to see the preview of the report?

Comment: no it is showing this error dialog only. If I click on ok it shows a blank white page

Comment: set datasource location of the report with new connection

Comment: Can you please provide a sample @Mahendra

Comment: Do the following steps:

1. Open the report in the crystal report.

2.Right click on Database -> Set Datasource Location.

3. Set Datasource Location window will appear and in the replace with section connect to the database and replace these tables with the tables in the current datasource by clicking the update button.

4. After updating close the Set Datasource Location window.

5. Go to 'Database menu' and Click 'Verify Database' and click on ’OK’.

6. Preview the report and the save the report.

Comment: I can't change any settings. I need to view the generated rpt in my winform.